# How to call Spark Java UDF in PySpark without using SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have implemented a UDF in Java.

```
package io.test;

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;

public class TestUDF implements UDF1<Integer, Integer> {

  @Override
  public Integer call(Integer i) throws Exception {
    // Some Operations
  }

}
```

I am using PySpark, so I am able to register the UDF in my Python driver script as follow :

```
session.udf.registerJavaFunction("test_udf", "io.test.TestUDF", IntegerType())
```

This UDF is now available to me to be used in SQL queries in Pyspark, e.g.

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("MyTable")
df2 = spark_session.sql("select test_udf(my_col) as mapped from MyTable")
```

However, I am wondering if there is a non-SQL way of achieving this in PySpark, e.g. something like below :

```
df.withColumn("mapped", functions.callUDF("test_udf", df.col("my_col")))
```

I checked and found that `callUDF()` function is available in Spark Java API but not in PySpark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

To use UDF implemented in Java, use it with [expr](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html):

```
.withColumn("asStr", F.expr("asStr(Number)"))
```

---

You can convert the function to udf using [functions.udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html) like this

```
TestUDF = udf(TestUDFFunction, IntegerType())
```

and use it as below:

```
myDF.withColumn("mapped", TestUDF(F.col("my_col")))
```

Example:

Input:

[image: Input]

UDF:

```
def asStr(num):
  return "Number is "+ str(num)

asStr_udf= F.udf(asStr, StringType())

df1.withColumn("asStr", asStr_udf(F.col("Number"))).show()
```

Output:

[image: Output]

Comment: My UDF is defined in Java, not in Python. How to make it work for that ?

Comment: In that case you can use expr [https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.expr.html] - `.withColumn("asStr", F.expr("asStr(Number)"))` @johngreen

Comment: @johngreen Sorry I missed that part, updated the answer